# Retrofit pasar String a url

Tags: java, kotlin, retrofit

Como puedo pasar la variable jornada al pulsar un boton a la clase apiInterface?

El fragment FragJornadas, de donde quiero pasar la variable a @Get

```
class FragJornadas : Fragment() {

var jornada =  "1"
var dataList = ArrayList<TodasModel>()
lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.jornadas_list, container, false)

    val miTexto: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_Jornadas)
    miTexto.text = (getString(R.string.num_jornada))

    val numJor = intArrayOf(R.id.tv_01, R.id.tv_02, R.id.tv_03, R.id.tv_04, R.id.tv_05,
        R.id.tv_06, R.id.tv_07, R.id.tv_08, R.id.tv_09, R.id.tv_10, R.id.tv_11, R.id.tv_12,
        R.id.tv_13, R.id.tv_14, R.id.tv_15, R.id.tv_16, R.id.tv_17, R.id.tv_18, R.id.tv_19,
        R.id.tv_20, R.id.tv_21, R.id.tv_22, R.id.tv_23, R.id.tv_24, R.id.tv_25, R.id.tv_26,
        R.id.tv_27, R.id.tv_28, R.id.tv_29, R.id.tv_30)

    val button = arrayOfNulls<Button>(numJor.size)

    for(i in numJor.indices){
        button[i] = view.findViewById(numJor[i]) as Button
        val buttonValue = i+1
        val buttonText = Integer.toString(buttonValue)

        button[i]!!.setOnClickListener {
            miTexto.text = getString(R.string.num_jornada) + " " + buttonText
            jornada = buttonText

            getData(jornada)
        }
    }

    return view
}


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val progressBar: ProgressBar = this.progressBar1

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)
    recyclerView.adapter= TodasAdapter(dataList,activity!!)
    recyclerView.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(activity!!,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)

    Thread(Runnable {
        activity!!.runOnUiThread {
            progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        try {
            var i = 0
            while(i < Int.MAX_VALUE){
                i++
            }
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        activity!!.runOnUiThread {
            progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }).start()
    getData(jornada)
}

private fun getData(jornada: String) {
    val call: Call<List<TodasModel>> = ApiFederacion.getClient.getTodasJuvenil(jornada)
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<TodasModel>> {

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<TodasModel>>?, response: Response<List<TodasModel>>?) {
            dataList.addAll(response!!.body()!!)
            recyclerView.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<TodasModel>>?, t: Throwable?) {
            //progerssProgressDialog.dismiss()
        }
    })
}
```

}

Y la clase ApiInterface para recibirlo
Siendo quela url que quiero conseguir es:
"server.php?action=getResultados&cmp=328&jor=1&tmp=2018/2019"

```
@GET("server.php?action=getResultados&cmp=328{jor}tmp=2018/2019")
fun getTodasJuvenil(
    @Path("jor") jornada: String
): Call<List<TodasModel>>
```

El error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "action=getResultados&cmp=328{jor}&tmp=2018/2019" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters 

at com.myapplication.Jornadas.FragJornadas.getData(FragJornadas.kt:91)        
at com.myapplication.Jornadas.FragJornadas.onViewCreated(FragJornadas.kt:87)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solucion:

```
@GET("server.php?action=getResultados&cmp=328&tmp=2018/2019")
        fun getTodasJuvenil(
            @Query("jor") jornada: String ): Call<List<TodasModel>>
```